# `git stash push`: Add custom message to default message

Tags: git, git-stash

When I do

```sh
git switch bugfix-scaling
# do some work
git stash push

git switch feature-colored-graph
# do some work
git stash push

git stash list
```

in the command line terminal, then I see something like

```
stash@{0}: WIP on feature-colored-graph: 1234567 Added RGB encoding
stash@{1}: WIP on bugfix-scaling: 2345678 X-axis scaling now works
```

I.e. I see from which branch the stash comes (`feature-colored-graph` resp. `bugfix-scaling`), and I see the latest commit hash (`1234567` resp. `2345678`) together with their respective commit message.

If instead I had done

```sh
git switch bugfix-scaling
# do some work
git stash push

git switch feature-colored-graph
# do some work
git stash push -m "Trying to match similar colors"

git stash list
```

then I would see

```
stash@{0}: On feature-colored-graph: Trying to match similar colors
stash@{1}: WIP on bugfix-scaling: 2345678 X-axis scaling now works
```

I.e. when I enter a custom stash message, then the listed stash entry does not show the last commit anymore.

It would be beneficial if I could *add* my own message `"Trying to match similar colors"` to the default message `"WIP on feature-colored-graph: 1234567 Added RGB encoding"`. Afterwards, I imagine `git stash list` to print something like

```sh
stash@{0}: WIP on feature-colored-graph: 1234567 Added RGB encoding
           Trying to match similar colors
stash@{1}: WIP on bugfix-scaling: 2345678 X-axis scaling now works Is this possible?
```

I am aware that anything like

```sh
git stash push -m <command to insert default commit message> -m "Trying to match similar colors"
```

will probably not work, since `git stash push` seems to accept at most one message and the last given message is kept.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the last commit message and insert it into the command line:

```
git stash push -m "$(git show --format=%s -s). Trying to match similar colors"
```

Works only with bash, not with cmd.

Comment: Nice, seems to work. Thank you! But what do you mean by "Works only with bash, not with cmd"? I just entered precisely what you suggested in my command line and it worked.

Comment: @NerdOnTour "*…in my command line … it worked.*" This means your command line is interpreted by Bash. `$()` is bash substitution syntax. It doesn't work with `cmd.exe`.

Comment: You do not necessarily need bash. The syntax `$(command)` is part of the POSIX shell specification. Many Unix-like shells support it. Even PowerShell seems to support it.